# Spikes added at corners of image when saving screenshot as png with thick rounded border

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, screenshot

When added thick rounded border to `UIImageView` & resize it to elliptical shape, spikes getting added at corners of `UIImageView`, when taking screenshot of `UIImageView` and  saved as png.

1) Default view when rounded border is added

[image: Default view when rounded border is added]

2) Resized `UIImageView` as elliptical shape

[image: Resized imageview as elliptical shape]

3) After saving screenshot as .png file

[image: After saving screenshot as .png file]

I tried following code for capturing the screenshot

```
-(UIImage *)captureImage
{
     //Capture entire screen
     if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) 
     {
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(appDelegate.templateFlag.view.frame.size, appDelegate.templateFlag.view.opaque, 1.5);
     }
     else
     {
         UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(appDelegate.templateFlag.view.frame.size, appDelegate.templateFlag.view.opaque, 2.0);
     }

    [appDelegate.viewController.vwEditorPanel.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return image;
}
```

Following code used for saving `image` in Doc directory

```
-(void)saveImage
{        
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation([self captureImage])];

    //Store image in document folder
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png",self.strProjectId]];
    [data writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];
}
```

Comment: 1. Why on earth are you using a scale factor of 1.5 for the image context? 2. Please show how you resize / reshape the image. 3. Is this on the simulator or a device, because renderInContext on layers with transforms doesn't always work too well on the simulator.

Comment: 1) Client is god and we have to implement what has been asked. Image context was small compared to screen resolution which was asked. We want captured image with high resolution.
2) We use CGAffinetransform to scale image and black frame is applied on border of the image layer.
3) We are testing on iPhone 5 as well as other devices too.

Comment: 1) Love it! Can you show the code you use to rescale the image?

Comment: We dont rescale image directly save it to doc directory.